# Batch filling in lookups in MS Access

Tags: ms-access-2010

I'm copying quite a lot of data from Excel into Access. The trouble is, I have a lookup field and I must select a value from it for each new row. There are about 1000 rows and I wondered if I can somehow fill in those lookups automatically.

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: I have a table. One field should contain text and another is a lookup. I'm copying text fields into the table from excel, but I need to fill in the lookup field somehow. Is there a way to automate this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a linked table to the Excel. Let's call it ExcelLinked.

Create a query with `ExcelLinked` and your lookup table, let's call it `tblLookupItems`.

The query will be:

```
INSERT INTO TargetTable (SELECT ExcelLinked.*, tblLookupItems.ID FROM ExcelLinked INNER JOIN tblLookupItems ON ExcelLinked.LookupItem = tblLookupItems.LookupItem)
```

However, if there are values in the Excel file that do not exist in the lookup table, you will have to decide whether you are willing to forgo those rows or use a lookup ID of 0 in which cae you should use a `LEFT JOIN` in the SQL query.

Comment: Shows "duplicate output destination 'LookupItem' " error